# EF6.1 Code First Mapping or Annotations for Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following two models that I'm trying to setup, but cannot figure out how to do it using data annotations or fluent API. Can anyone advise either the proper annotations or Fluent API code?

```
public class Vehicle
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int JobID { get; set; }
   public int StatusID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual Job Job { get; set }
   public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int VehicleID { get; set; }
   public int StatusID { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }

   public virtual Vehicle Vehicle{ get; set; }
   public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the reference to the Job model from Vehicle, and from Vehicle to Job. In the database, the Jobs tables holds all jobs pending or completed. There may or may not be a vehicle associated with it (when a job is in progress or complete, a vehicle will be associated with it). For the vehicles table, the JobID represents the current job assigned to the vehicle (if it's assigned a job) and will constantly change through the day, but should have no effect on the Jobs table.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet outlines a fluent code-first example of the relationship you describe:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<Job>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
        mb.Entity<Vehicle>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
        mb.Entity<Vehicle>().HasOptional(x => x.Job).WithOptionalDependent();

        // ... other config, constraints, etc
    }
}
```

And to get Jobs associated with vehicles:

```
using (var context = new AppDataContext())
{
    var query = context.Vehicles.Where(x => x.Job != null).Select(x => x.Job);
    // ...
}
```

IMHO, the explicit foreign key properties should be kept out of the model unless strictly needed.  This tends to make life easier and keeps the code clean.

Hope this is along the lines of what you're looking for...

---

P.S. - At the risk of 'just posting links' - If you already have a database (as implied in your question), it might be worth considering a Database First approach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj206878.aspx   ..or Code First with an existing database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620